# Getting Tweets from a user after a certain Tweet ID

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I know that for a particular request, Twitter returns only about 200 tweets per request. This is the code I have written

```
import urllib, json
import sys
import tweepy

def twitter_fetch(screen_name = "prateekyes",maxnumtweets=10):

    consumer_token = ""
    consumer_secret = ""
    access_token = ""
    access_secret = ""

    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_token,consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token,access_secret)

    api  = tweepy.API(auth)
    statuses = 0
    for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline,id=screen_name).items(10):
        json_str = status._json
        print json_str["user"]["statuses_count"]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    twitter_fetch('BarackObama',200)
```

Can I give any parameter in the Cursor() method, so that I can specify the greatest Tweet ID number and tell it to get tweets less than that?

Answer (score 2):

**max_id** parameter can be passed. for example

```
for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline,id=screen_name,max_id=<some number>).items(10):
    json_str = status._json
    print json_str["user"]["statuses_count"]
```

It gives all tweets with the TweetID less than or equal to that ID number